# Access query to fetch Date in cell containing Comments

Tags: sql, function, ms-access, text, datetime-format

I have a Data set that consists of a Comments Column in which consists of a Date qithin the texts, this date has to be fetched and placed to column GMS_Date with condition where the GMS Column must be "Y" and then moved to the Date Created column.

[image: here looks the dummy of the Data]

As there are constraints i am suppose to use Access DB and i have made use of this Trim function in Update statement as below:

```
UPDATE tbl_Pp SET tbl_Pp.Date_GMS = Trim(Mid([Comments],Find("Date Created:",[Comments])+14,10))WHERE (((tbl_Pp.GMS)="Y"));
```

here it is throwing error for **Find** Function within **Trim** Function.

Please suggest any alternatives or possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to guess, that there is no *Find* function in VBA.

So try this:

```
UPDATE 
    tbl_Pp 
SET 
    tbl_Pp.Date_GMS = DateValue(Mid([Comments], InStr([Comments], "Date Created") + 14, 10))
WHERE 
    tbl_Pp.GMS = "Y";
```